# Syntax to call CoInitialize(); from PHP?

Tags: php, com, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to hack together a server that turns HTML into native Word docs.  It works, but some of the time I get the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `word.application': CoInitialize has not been called.
```

I'm using PHP and not ASP or something more Microsoft-y because it is supposed to just be a quick project.

I initialize a COM object like this:

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
```

Could anyone tell me how I can call CoInitialize() from PHP?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you don't have any rogue copies of WINWORD.EXE hanging around. I ran into this error, and when I checked, I had 36 copies of WINWORD.EXE running. I had apparently missed some logic in disconnecting from the COM object, so every time I reloaded the script, the existing WINWORD was left in limbo while a new one launched. Once I nuked all the WINWORDs, the error went away.